# how to setup the webpack to make all sites I visited a proxy?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

as we all know, if we start webpack, it will go to the site like `localhost: 8080`, now I want to make all the sites we visit a proxy, it seems like that when I go to `localhost: 8080`, in fact I visit `www.abc.com`, how to set up the webpack in the config?

I do it below, but not work:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/": {
      target: "www.a.com"
    }
  }
}
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add prefix `http://` to `www.abc.com`